# Proper referencing from one sheet to another, without #ref

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

So, I got 2 sheets:

1st Sheet is **Main sheet** one with the data where I will periodically update (edit, add or delete) data, got like 800 rows.

2nd Sheet is actually lookup sheet where I have same data as are on Sheet1 but with some additinally calculations, like broaden sheet.

I wanna have it properly updated, in a sense of:

- when adding new row in Main Sheet1 I am not getting it populated on Sheet2

  - when I delete row in a Main Sheet(1) I am getting **#ref** error in Sheet2

    - the only thing that works is editing row.

I tried:

```
=OFFSET(SummaryAll!A2;0;0)
```

referncing: `=SummaryAll!A2`

```
INDEX/MATCH combo
```

or something like this: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Row(Helper!C2),Column(Helper!C2),,,"txt"))`

Well, I dont know actually, referencing itself is not a problem, but how I am avoiding error #ref and is there a way to dynamically move my rows when one is deleted from the main sheet?!

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned `INDEX` is the way forward =). Can you explain why you tagged `Excel-vba`?

Comment: Well, people with VBA knowledge usually can and might do excel as well. So, more help I received more things and ways can person learn.  

It is okay, I removed it.

Comment: As JvdV already confirmed, try `=INDEX(SummaryAll!A:A,2)` - this should prevent any potential `#REF` errors from occurring.

Comment: @JustynaMK  Well I edited my post properly, 2 sheets with almost the same data, where I need to index/match from S1 to S2. So this Index that you wrote is not functioning, isnt matching anything only first row, but there are 800 left. That is reason I looking for part of the function where I can skip error when deleting some rows.

Comment: If I understand your set up properly, then on Sheet2 you want to recreate what is happening on Sheet1 (i.e. if you remove/add rows, Sheet2 will update accordingly). In such case, I'd recommend using on Sheet2 `=INDEX(SummaryAll!$A$1:$A$800,ROW())` and drag it down to row no 800.

Comment: @JustynaMK Very much appreciated! I solved my "issue" :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all comments, lets sum it:

THX to @JvdV and @JustynaMK for actually simple as a day suggest and solution:

So it is possible to use (at least two approaches):

```
=INDEX(SummaryAll!A:A;ROW())
```

or one of my ways but requires a bit more refreshes with functions

```
=@SummaryAll!A3:INDEX(SummaryAll!A:A;COUNTA(SummaryAll!A:A))
```

And lastly (in my case works also) using Power Query, after adding new data just hit refresh.